# uib-datepicker : display issue when used in a table

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to use a uib-datepicker in a table :

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped"  >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="col-md-2"><span>Date</span></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="materiel in vm.chantier.listeMateriels track by materiel.id">
                <td class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{vm.formatDate}}"uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="materiel.date"
                               is-open="materiel.isOpen" ng-change="vm.dateDebutChanged()"  />
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.openCalendarMateriel($event, materiel)">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </td>                
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

But here is what I get : 
Before clicking : 
[image]

After clicking:
[image]

It seems that the calendar is truncated with the table borders, I would like it to appear above my table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `class="table-responsive"` from your parent `div`: it truncate the datepicker.

### [Demo on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b8s3dm0d/)

Comment: thank you! works perfectly now. Hard to solve this pb without good knowledge in css...